# Why am I getting an error of '6' for creating another column base from a value from another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Data can be found here https://github.com/dqc002/Learning/blob/main/Data%20gathered.csv

I'm trying to create another column base from a value from another column and it's giving me an error of

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-4bdbdff831dc> in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 data['STATUS'] = data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT[x])
     17 data

~\anacondafinal\envs\forcartopy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-79-4bdbdff831dc> in <lambda>(x)
     14 
     15 
---> 16 data['STATUS'] = data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT[x])
     17 data

KeyError: '6'
```

```
data=pd.read_csv('Data gathered1.csv')
data

ACT = {'0': 'No Activity', 
     '1A' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED',
     '1B' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED', 
     '2A' :'INVESTIGATION',
     '2B': 'INVESTIGATION',
     '3':'CORRECTIVE ACTION PLANNING',
     '4': 'IMPLEMENT ACTION',
    '5': 'MONITOR ACTION',
     '6A':'ACTION COMPLETED',
     '6B':'ACTION COMPLETED',
    '6C': 'INACTIVE',
     '6D': 'INACTIVE'
      }


   data['STATUS'] = data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT[x])
   data
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use 'map' here. Based on the dataset here's the input/output via map-

```
ACT = {'0': 'No Activity', 
     '1A' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED',
     '1B' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED', 
     '2A' :'INVESTIGATION',
     '2B': 'INVESTIGATION',
     '3':'CORRECTIVE ACTION PLANNING',
     '4': 'IMPLEMENT ACTION',
    '5': 'MONITOR ACTION',
     '6A':'ACTION COMPLETED',
     '6B':'ACTION COMPLETED',
    '6C': 'INACTIVE',
     '6D': 'INACTIVE'
      }

df['ACT-STATUS 5.236'] = df['ACT-STATUS 5.236'].astype(str)
df['STATUS'] = df['ACT-STATUS 5.236'].map(ACT)
```

```
print(df[['ACT-STATUS 5.236','STATUS']])
  ACT-STATUS 5.236                   STATUS
0                0              No Activity
1                0              No Activity
2               2A            INVESTIGATION
3               2A            INVESTIGATION
4                6                      NaN
5               1A  CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED
6                6                      NaN
7                6                      NaN
8                6                      NaN
9              nan                      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the column headers of your `Data gathered.csv` have some spaces like  `FILE NAME` and extra data like `ACT-STATUS 5.236`.

```
COUNTY,Division, FILE NAME,File Number,LOCATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,CONTAMINANTS,DATE,ENF-STATUS,ACT-STATUS 5.236,Category
```

Then when you do `data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT[x])`, pandas will treat value of `ACT-STATUS` column as `x`, then use `x` as key of `ACT` dictionary to find value. However, your `ACT` dictionary doesn't have key `6`. So it gives you the error. You may want

```py
import numpy as np
data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT.get(x, np.NaN))
```

where `ACT.get(x, np.NaN)` will return `NaN` if `x` is not found in key of `ACT`.

`data['ACT-STATUS 5.236'].unique()` gives the following result

```
['0' '2A' '6' '1A' '4' '5' '4,5A' '2B' '3' '6C']
```

`4,5A` is also an outliner value. You may need to come up a workaround to handle this.